# Nested loop logic

Tags: php, nested-loops

I have this code block

```
<?php

$myArray = array('a', 'b', 'c');

foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) {
    echo $v;

    for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
        if ($i == $k) {
            break;
        }

        echo $i; //a1234bc1 
    }
}


?>
```

and I have no problem with it until I get to the value after c. Shouldn't be 1234 instead of 1 ? am I missing something?

Comment: want this? a1234b1234c1234

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @FatalError because your $i and $k values are equal to 2(both are equal) at that stage.

Comment: yes,it is inside forloop at first it prints $i as 1 .then $i is incremented to 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106331/discussion-between-syed-mohamed-and-fatalerror).

Answer (score 2):

Because,

1. In the first iteration in foreach value of `$k` is `0` and there is no `0` in for loop, it covers all and print all 1 to 4, so output is `a1234`
2. In the second iteration in foreach value of `$k` is `1` and for loop start from `1`,so in if condition it is in first iteration, so loop stop in first iteration of for loop and print only b , so output is `a1234b`
3. similarly in third iteration in foreach value of `$k` is `2` and for loop start from `1`,so in if condition it is in second iteration, so loop stop in second iteration of for loop after print c1 , so output is `a1234bc1`

I think now its clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You `foreach ($myArray as $k => $v)` loop is executed **3 times** as `$myArray` has 3 Elements.

**First run**

`$k` = 0 which is the index of the first element, `$v` = "a"

```
echo $v; // Outputs a
```

Output of your loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) { ... }
```

Outputs all numbers from 1 to 5 and stops once the exact value of `$k` is met. `$k` is 0 so the condition (break) never gets triggered. Hence all numbers from 1 to 5 are echoed.

Output so far:

> a1234

**Second run**

`$k` = 1 which is the index of the second element, `$v` = "b"

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) { ... }
```

Output of your loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++)
```

Outputs all numbers from 1 to 5 and stops once the exact value of `$k` is met. As `$k` is 1 the `break` gets executed on first run of llop, hence no output.

Output so far:

> a1234b

**Third run**

`$k` = 2 which is the index of the third element, `$v` = "c"

```
echo $v; // Outputs c
```

Output of your loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) { ... }
```

Outputs all numbers from 1 to 5 and stops once the exact value of `$k` is met. As `$k` euqals 2 this time the loop gets executed once outputting 1. On second run the `break` executes and terminates oputput

Final output:

> a1234bc1

Comment: output for first iteration will be a1234 not a12345

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$myArray = array('a', 'b', 'c');

foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) {
    echo $v;
    for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
        echo $i; //a1234b1234c1234
    }
}
```

Remove if condition .

Answer (score 0):

**1st Iteration:**
 1st loop
      $k = 0; $v = a;
      2nd loop
       $i doesn't equal $k;
    Output: a1234

**2nd Iteration:**
 1st loop
 $k = 1; $v = b;
  2nd loop
   $i equals $k(i.e 1);
 Output: a1234b

**3nd Iteration:**
 1st loop
 $k = 2; $v = c;
  2nd loop
   $i equals $k(i.e 2);
 Output: a1234bc1